# PhpStorm/git wants to commit all files in dual boot setup (LF vs CRLF)

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have a repository on a data partition. The files were created in Windows.
I now opened the project from a dual boot Ubuntu installation and PhpStorm/git says that all files have been changed and should be committed.

However, the only changes are:
Contents have differences only in line separators. 
Remote LF Your Version CRLF

Is there some way to ignore the Linefeed type?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `.gitattributes` file in the root of your repository with this content

```
* -text
```

It should force git not to convert line endings on commit operations.